# Is it possible to call the Nikon SDK from Swift?

Tags: swift, sdk, wrapper

I am trying to interface with a Z series camera using the Nikon SDK, which I assume provides a C interface (Maid3.h, Maid3d1.h). I have included the MAID headers in the bridging header.

Bridging-Header.h

```
#include    "Foundation/Foundation.h"
#include    "Maid3.h"
#include    "Maid3d1.h"
```

But am having some trouble figuring out how to call some of the MAID APIs.  For example:

Loading the library - their sample code (*.cpp) is as follows:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
SLONG CallMAIDEntryPoint( 
        LPNkMAIDObject  pObject,                // module, source, item, or data object
        ULONG               ulCommand,          // Command, one of eNkMAIDCommand
        ULONG               ulParam,                // parameter for the command
        ULONG               ulDataType,         // Data type, one of eNkMAIDDataType
        NKPARAM         data,                   // Pointer or long integer
        LPNKFUNC            pfnComplete,        // Completion function, may be NULL
        NKREF               refComplete )       // Value passed to pfnComplete
{
    return (*(LPMAIDEntryPointProc)g_pMAIDEntryPoint)( 
                        pObject, ulCommand, ulParam, ulDataType, data, pfnComplete, refComplete );
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
BOOL Search_Module( void* Path )
{

    CFStringRef modulePath = NULL;
    
    CFStringRef moduleName = CFSTR( "Type0024 Module.bundle" );
    CFBundleRef bundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    if(bundle != NULL)
    {
        CFURLRef executableURL = CFBundleCopyExecutableURL( bundle );
        if(executableURL != NULL)
        {
            CFURLRef parentFolderURL = CFURLCreateCopyDeletingLastPathComponent( kCFAllocatorDefault, executableURL );
            if(parentFolderURL != NULL)
            {
                CFURLRef moduleURL = CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent( kCFAllocatorDefault, parentFolderURL, moduleName, FALSE );
                if(moduleURL != NULL)
                {
                    if(CFURLResourceIsReachable( moduleURL, NULL ))
                    {
                        modulePath = CFURLCopyFileSystemPath( moduleURL, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle );
                    }
                    CFRelease( moduleURL );
                }
                CFRelease( parentFolderURL );
            }
            CFRelease( executableURL );
        }
    }
    
    Boolean result = FALSE;
    if(modulePath != NULL)
    {
        result = CFStringGetCString( modulePath, (char *)Path, PATH_MAX, kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
        CFRelease( modulePath );
    }
    return result;

}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
BOOL Load_Module( void* Path )
{

    CFStringRef modulePath = CFStringCreateWithCString( kCFAllocatorDefault, (const char *)Path, kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
    if(modulePath != NULL)
    {
        CFURLRef moduleURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath( kCFAllocatorDefault, modulePath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, TRUE );
        if(moduleURL != NULL)
        {
            if(gBundle != NULL)
            {
                CFRelease( gBundle );
                gBundle = NULL;
            }
            gBundle = CFBundleCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, moduleURL );
            CFRelease( moduleURL );
        }
        CFRelease( modulePath );
    }
    
    if(gBundle == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    
    // Load and link dynamic CFBundle object
    if(!CFBundleLoadExecutable(gBundle))
    {
        CFRelease( gBundle );
        gBundle = NULL;
        return FALSE;
    }
    
    // Get entry point from BundleRef
    // Set the pointer for Maid entry point LPMAIDEntryPointProc type variabl
    g_pMAIDEntryPoint = (LPMAIDEntryPointProc)CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName( gBundle, CFSTR("MAIDEntryPoint") );
    return (g_pMAIDEntryPoint != NULL);

}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
BOOL Command_Open( NkMAIDObject* pParentObj, NkMAIDObject* pChildObj, ULONG ulChildID )
{
    SLONG lResult = CallMAIDEntryPoint( pParentObj, kNkMAIDCommand_Open, ulChildID, 
                                    kNkMAIDDataType_ObjectPtr, (NKPARAM)pChildObj, NULL, NULL );
    return lResult == kNkMAIDResult_NoError;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
BOOL Command_Close( LPNkMAIDObject pObject )
{
    SLONG nResult = CallMAIDEntryPoint( pObject, kNkMAIDCommand_Close, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL );

    return nResult == kNkMAIDResult_NoError;
}
```

My conversion of that to Swift is as follows:

```
var gBundle: CFBundle? = nil
var g_pMAIDEntryPoint: LPMAIDEntryPointProc?
var g_bFileRemoved: UCHAR     = 0
var g_ulCameraType: ULONG     = 0    // CameraType

func Search_Module()->String?
{
    var modulePath: CFString? = nil
    
    let moduleName = "Type0024 Module.bundle" as CFString
    let bundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    if(bundle != nil)
    {
        let executableURL = CFBundleCopyExecutableURL( bundle );
        if(executableURL != nil)
        {
            let parentFolderURL = CFURLCreateCopyDeletingLastPathComponent( kCFAllocatorDefault, executableURL );
            if(parentFolderURL != nil)
            {
                let moduleURL = CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent( kCFAllocatorDefault, parentFolderURL, moduleName, false );
                if(moduleURL != nil)
                {
                    if(CFURLResourceIsReachable( moduleURL, nil ))
                    {
                        modulePath = CFURLCopyFileSystemPath( moduleURL, CFURLPathStyle.cfurlposixPathStyle );
                    }
                    //CFRelease( moduleURL );
                }
                //CFRelease( parentFolderURL );
            }
            //CFRelease( executableURL );
        }
    }
    
    
    if(modulePath != nil)
    {
        //result = CFStringGetCString( modulePath, path, Int(PATH_MAX), CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue );
        //CFRelease( modulePath );
        return modulePath as String?
    }
    return nil
  
}

func Load_Module( path: String )->Bool
{
   
    let modulePath = CFStringCreateWithCString( kCFAllocatorDefault, path, CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue);
    
    if(modulePath != nil)
    {
        let moduleURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath( kCFAllocatorDefault, modulePath, CFURLPathStyle.cfurlposixPathStyle, true );
        
        if(moduleURL != nil)
        {
            if(gBundle != nil)
            {
                //CFRelease( gBundle );
                gBundle = nil;
            }
            gBundle = CFBundleCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, moduleURL );
            //CFRelease( moduleURL );
        }
        //CFRelease( modulePath );
    }
    
    if(gBundle == nil)
    {
        return false
    }
    
    // Load and link dynamic CFBundle object
    if(!CFBundleLoadExecutable(gBundle))
    {
        //CFRelease( gBundle );
        gBundle = nil;
        return false
    }
    
    // Get entry point from BundleRef
    // Set the pointer for Maid entry point LPMAIDEntryPointProc type variabl
    g_pMAIDEntryPoint = CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName( gBundle, "MAIDEntryPoint" as CFString) as? LPMAIDEntryPointProc
    return (g_pMAIDEntryPoint != nil)
}
func CallMAIDEntryPoint(
    _ pObject: LPNkMAIDObject,                // module, source, item, or data object
    _ ulCommand: ULONG                ,            // Command, one of eNkMAIDCommand
    _ ulParam: ULONG                ,                // parameter for the command
    _ ulDataType: ULONG                ,            // Data type, one of eNkMAIDDataType
    _ data: NKPARAM            ,                    // Pointer or long integer
    _ pfnComplete: LPNKFUNC?            ,            // Completion function, may be NULL
    _ refComplete: NKREF?                 )->Int32?        // Value passed to pfnComplete
{
    return g_pMAIDEntryPoint?(
                        pObject, ulCommand, ulParam, ulDataType, data, pfnComplete, refComplete );
}
func Command_Open( pParentObj: LPNkMAIDObject, pChildObj: NKPARAM, ulChildID: ULONG)->Bool
{
    let lResult = CallMAIDEntryPoint( pParentObj, kNkMAIDCommand_Open.rawValue, ulChildID,
                                      kNkMAIDDataType_ObjectPtr.rawValue, pChildObj, nil, nil );
    return lResult == kNkMAIDResult_NoError.rawValue;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
func Command_Close( pObject: LPNkMAIDObject)->Bool
{
    let nResult = CallMAIDEntryPoint( pObject, kNkMAIDCommand_Close.rawValue, 0, 0, 0, nil, nil );

    return nResult == kNkMAIDResult_NoError.rawValue;
}
```

However the call to ge the function entry point generates a warning indicating that it will always fail.

```
g_pMAIDEntryPoint = CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName( gBundle, "MAIDEntryPoint" as CFString) as? LPMAIDEntryPointProc

Cast from 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer?' to unrelated type 'LPMAIDEntryPointProc' (aka '@convention(c) (Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<tagNkMAIDObject>>, UInt32, UInt32, UInt32, UInt64, Optional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>, Optional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>) -> Int32') always fails
```

The definition is as follows:

```
// Client/Module Interface and Callback Functions
typedef W32EXPORT NKERROR CALLPASCAL WINAPI MAIDEntryPointProc (
    LPNkMAIDObject  pObject,                // module, source, item, or data object
    ULONG               ulCommand,          // Command, one of eNkMAIDCommand
    ULONG               ulParam,                // parameter for the command
    ULONG               ulDataType,         // Data type, one of eNkMAIDDataType
    NKPARAM         data,                   // Pointer or long integer
    LPNKFUNC            pfnComplete,        // Completion function, may be NULL
    NKREF               refComplete );      // Value passed to pfnComplete
typedef MAIDEntryPointProc FAR* LPMAIDEntryPointProc;
```

So I have a few questions:

1. Is it feasible to call the Nikon SDK libraries from Swift
2. If so is the above approach the best way to call the functions in the library
3. How do I call the c functions (and I assume they are c functions) from Swift?
4. It also seems the library needs to be loaded and retained in some way - is there a way to create a Swift object to wrap the library and if so where can I find examples of how to do so?

Comment: As-is, this question is a bit too broad to be a good fit for Stack Overflow -- you'll want to edit the post to focus specifically on one problem. However, to provide a few pointers (no pun intended): 1-2: Yes, in general anything you can do from C you can do from Swift -- it's just a bit awkward sometimes because of Swift's stricter type system, especially when pointers are involved.

Comment: To answer your specific error: you can't use `as` to cast between pointer types in Swift. Instead, you have to use [the `UnsafeMutableRawPointer.load(as:)` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablerawpointer/2428566-load), as in `CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(...).load(as: LPMAIDEntryPointProc.self)`. For a more general introduction to Swift's pointer types, [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10167) looks like it might be helpful (I haven't watched it though, so no promises).

Comment: Hmm ok thanks, looks like I might need to find someone with more current knowledge in the space.

Comment: @NobodyNada - your .load(as:) works fine - after I figured out how to find the module in the plugins folder !  The video was not very helpful btw.  So the function is loading now it seems but the how do I call the function with the function pointer?  Just using ptr(...) crashes - it couldn't be that simple could it.  I guess I could be messing up the parameters being passed in - in which case I'll post another question.